# Flailing in the dark on UWP and a ListView of thumbnails that will not load. Need more experienced advice

Tags: listview, uwp, loading, thumbnails, virtualization

Here's the problem:
I've got a previewer that generates a thumbnail for each page of a document and records the paths to these thumbnails in a list. When I feed that list to a ListView (here's the XAML)

```
<ListView Grid.Column="1" x:Name="PART_ThumbList" 
          MaxWidth="200">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

one of a few different things happens, depending on how many thumbnails there are:
If there's just one, it may load ok, or not.
If there's around 12, they do not load at all.
If there's several hundred, the first one loads, followed by a lot of blank space. If you scroll down a ways, you start seeing thumbnails, and if you then scroll back up, the blank thumbnails have all been filled in. This behavior made me suspect that virtualization was at fault, but the documentation suggests virtualization isn't even turned on unless you specify the height of the control *and* your list source implements ISupportIncrementalLoading (mine is an ObservableCollection) under the hood.

Here's what currently happens under the hood: the ListView is part of a custom control backed by a class, and is called out as one of the class's template parts. When OnApplyTemplate gets triggered, the ListView's ItemsSource is assigned to a new ObservableCollection. Then that collection is populated from the list of thumbnail paths. I used to just link the list directly to the listview, but changed to this when that wasn't working.

I have tried setting DataFetchSize both high and low. I have tried fixing the height of the ListView. I have tried setting IncrementalLoadingThreshold high and low. I have tried setting IncrementalLoadingTrigger to "Edge" and to "None" (that last in an attempt to explicitly disable virtualization and just load all contents). I have tried forcing the thumbnails to be very, very small, in case memory had something to do with it. I have tried changing to a ListBox (I vaguely recall that they do not virtualize). I've even tried ditching the itemtemplate and populating the list with images from the code, but I got a "marshaled on another thread" exception and had no idea what to do with that.

The option I am looking at now is to go through every step of the tutorial on making an itemssource class that explicitly implements virtualization, but it looks to be around 2 hrs of refactoring, minimum, and I'm not about to invest that kind of time unless someone can tell me it is likely to help.

I'm a UWP n00b wandering in the dark here. Can anyone shed some light?

-Z

Comment: I set a local image as Thumblie and when the list download the url , I replace the local image to url image.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what's the actually issue you met?  You mentioned many trying ways but what you're trying to resolve? Did you just want to disable the virtualization for the `ListView`?

Comment: The issue that I'm trying to solve is how to get images from the HDD to display in the image control. In theory, when I set the Source property to the full path of the image, it should load, but that's not always happening - sometimes they load and sometimes they don't. I was asking about virtualization because they way they loaded in if you scrolled far enough suggested it was a virtualization problem.